# upscaling a video to 8k webm/mov without taking 20 hours or 10-100GB disk space

Tags: video, ffmpeg

In other video formats, you could convert a video, changing it's resolution, making it have a higher frame size, without increasing file size. For example you could have a mp4 h264 video, one in 4k one in 480p, but both being the same filesize and same video, one is just upscaled. I'm trying to do it with webm or mov. However, all webm attempts are taking 10+ hours, and all mov attemps, are trying to encode the video in the higher bitrate than the source material, causing 100 gig files.

How do I efficiently upscale a webm or mov video?

edit: managed to use premiere to cut down the render time of a mov to 3 hours using a 4k bitrate limit. However that's still very long.

Comment: *you could convert a video, changing it's resolution, making it have a higher frame size, without increasing file size* --> not true. If you're seeing this, it means you are rendering the smaller resolution video with a much higher bitrate than needed, or the higher resolution video with a much lower bitrate.

Comment: Why do you want to upscale? Why not just let the player upscale?